# string.Format exception Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-formatting, resourcedictionary

I received the following error from a `string.Format(...)` operation:

> ***System.FormatException*** - Input string was not in a correct format.

I have a resource dictionary which contains an entry with a basic html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>

    <style>
        * { 
            margin: 0; 
            padding: 0; 
        }

        body { 
            font-family: 'Arial, Verdana', Fallback, sans-serif; 
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        table { 
            background-color: #eeeeee; 
            width: 100%; 
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    text<br />

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 1</td>
            <td>{0}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 2</td>
            <td>{1}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 3</td>
            <td>{2}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 4</td>
            <td>{3}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 5</td>
            <td>{4}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 6</td>
            <td>{5}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 7</td>
            <td>{6}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />

    <h1>Header1</h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 8: {7}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
</body>
```

The `string.Format(...)` operations looks like this:

```
var emailHtml = string.Format(
                    WebUtility.HtmlEncode(EmailResource.EmailTemplate),
                    "text1",
                    "text2",
                    "text3",
                    "text4",
                    "text5",
                    "text6",
                    "text7",
                    "text8");
```

Does anyone know what error I made?
Isn't it possible to fill in the placeholders in the resource dictionary like this?

Comment: I don't think you should be HtmlEncoding the entire template.. you should only encode the individual text1, text2, etc, values if they need to be encoded (in this case they all do)

Comment: If i were a betting man, those unescaped `{` and `}` (in your CSS definition) are the cause. Braces in a format input must be escaped (`{` => `{{`, `}`} => `}}`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a lot of curly braces which are not format specifiers, for example:

```
    { 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
    }
```

Either you need to duplicate them:

```
    {{
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
    }}
```

Or using different formatting approach (like template engine).